# Raise UserError only if none fields selected

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I added my custom field to res.partner model and when I'm creating partner if branch_id is checked I want to that one of 3 fields should be selected. If some of the fields are not selected then I want to raise UserError.

But now it raises UserError even if I one of the fields is selected.

```py
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

 branch_id = fields.Many2one('branch.responsibility','Responsibility by branch')
 drawer_id = fields.Many2one(
        'furniture.parts.type', string='Drawer Type',
        domain=[('type', '=', 'drawer')], )
flexible_id = fields.Many2one(
        'furniture.parts.type', string='Flexible Type',
        domain=[('type', '=', 'flexible')],)
 runner_id = fields.Many2one(
        'furniture.parts.type', string='Runner Type',
        domain=[('type', '=', 'runner')], )


@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('branch_id'):
            if not vals['drawer_id'] or not vals['flexible_id'] or not vals['runner_id']:
                raise UserError('You need to chose values from notebook raport data')
        return super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
```

UPDATE.

for write method, I tried this as CZoellner suggested for create but always get True True True for `fields_to_check_in_vals`

```py
 @api.multi
     def write(self, vals):
         if vals.get('branch_id') or vals.get('drawer_id') or vals.get('flexible_id') or vals.get('runner_id') or
 vals.get('group_1_id') or vals.get('group_2_id')or
 vals.get('group_3_id'):
             fields_to_check = ['drawer_id', 'flexible_id', 'runner_id', 'group_1_id', 'group_2_id', 'group_3_id']
             fields_to_check_in_vals = [f in self for f in fields_to_check]
             if not any(fields_to_check_in_vals):
                 raise UserError('If branch is selected then you need to select one of the fields from data raport')
>         return super(ResPartner, self).write(vals)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic says, that all 3 fields have to be set. You could use `any` here:

```py
if vals.get('branch_id'):
    fields_to_check = ['drawer_id', 'flexible_id', 'runner_id']
    fields_to_check_in_vals = [f in vals for f in fields_to_check]
    if not any(fields_to_check_in_vals):
        raise UserError()
```

Edit: the `write` method is a bit more tricky. Usually it is a multi record method, so a for each loop on self should be implemented. Then you'll need to use either `getattr` or just (it's suggested in the Odoo doc) treat the recordset like a dict. And then it could be, that the change happens right on the write call. So you have to check both the persisted and the new values:

```py
for record in self:
    if vals.get('branch_id'):
        fields_to_check = ['drawer_id', 'flexible_id', 'runner_id']
        fields_to_check_dict = {f:record[f] for f in fields_to_check}
        fields_to_check_dict.update({f:f in vals for f in fields_to_check})
        if not any(fields_to_check_dict.values()):
            raise UserError()
```

That's a bit complicated. You could also first call `super` and just check after that. Raising an exception will rollback all changes, so nothing will happen.

```py
res = super(MyModel, self).write(vals)
for record in self:
    if vals.get('branch_id'):
        fields_to_check = ['drawer_id', 'flexible_id', 'runner_id']
        fields_to_check_in_record = [record[f] for f in fields_to_check]
        if not any(fields_to_check_in_record):
            raise UserError()
return res
```

Comment: in fields_to_check_in_vals i receive always <type 'list'>: [True, True, True, True, True, True] but those fields are empty(not selected).

Comment: Ok that is weird, do `vals.get(f)` then instead of `f in vals`.

Comment: updated my question maybe you can share some wisdom :)

Comment: Added a solution for write method.

Comment: Thank you for such deep explanation